# Cannot catch in the initialize list

Tags: c++

For the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Str
{
    Str() { throw 100; }
};

class Cla
{
public:
    Cla()
    try : m_mem() { }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cout << "Catch block is called"<< std::endl;
    }
private:
    Str m_mem;
};

int main()
{
    Cla obj;
}
```

I tried to catch the exception in the catch block. But after the catch block is run, the system still calls std::terminate to terminate the program. I didn't re-throw the exception in the catch block, can you tell me why the system crashes? Thanks!

Here is a test on compiler explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/74sTcxrY4

Comment: The end of a function try-catch block automatically rethrows any exception

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're contradicting yourself.

> I tried to catch the exception in the catch block. But after the catch block is run

If the catch block is run, you *succeeded* catching the exception from the initializer list. You're just surprised by what happened next.

First, let's think about what happens when a constructor throws: the object is not constructed. Right? the constructor never finished setting it up, so you can't use it for anything.

```
int main() {
   Cla obj;     // member subobject constructor throw, but we caught it!
   obj.print(); // but we still can't use this here, because the constructor never completed
}
```

So it doesn't really make sense to let you swallow the exception here. You can't handle it, because you can't go back and re-try constructing your member and base-class subobjects. If you don't have a properly-constructed object, the only way C++ has of dealing with that is to unwind the block scope in which that object would otherwise be assumed to be ... well, a real object.

Hence, per the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function-try-block):

> Every catch-clause in the function-try-block for a constructor must terminate by throwing an exception. If the control reaches the end of such handler, the current exception is automatically rethrown as if by throw;. The return statement is not allowed in any catch clause of a constructor's function-try-block.

... and equivalently in the standard ([draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/except.handle#13))

> The currently handled exception is rethrown if control reaches the end of a handler of the *function-try-block* of a constructor or destructor.
> Otherwise, flowing off the end of the *compound-statement* of a handler of a *function-try-block* is equivalent to flowing off the end of the *compound-statement* of that function (see [stmt.return])

Comment: Cheers, I was already hunting down the appropriate clause. I like to link cppreference since it's usually friendlier, but actually the standard is very clear on this one.

Answer (score 9):

There is no way to swallow an exception in a constructor's function catch block. It will necessarily throw something, the caught exception if control reaches the end of the catch block. The only way around this is to `std::terminate` or otherwise abort before then.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function-try-block):

> Every catch-clause in the function-try-block for a constructor must terminate by throwing an exception. If the control reaches the end of such handler, the current exception is automatically rethrown as if by throw;. The return statement is not allowed in any catch clause of a constructor's function-try-block.

This is intentional and beneficial. It would not make sense to return from a constructor that did not complete, it would allow an object to be accessible despite not actually having been created.

Such a catch block can be used to log errors, release resources (if you aren't using RAII) and perform other similar cleanup. But it can't prevent an exception from propagating.